# UIScrollView with UIButton : buttons appear only after scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I've made my own `UIScrollView`.

In `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`, I've drawn my button like that :

```
- (void) createView {
CGFloat currentY = 0;
CGFloat currentX = 0;
CGFloat currentH = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [images count]; i++) {
    UIImage *img = [images objectAtIndex:i]; 

    CGSize cropParam = [[finalCrops objectAtIndex:i] CGSizeValue];
    CGSize imgSize = [[finalSizes objectAtIndex:i] CGSizeValue];

    UIImage *newImg = nil;

    if (imgSize.width > 0) {
        newImg = [img resize:imgSize];
    }

    if (cropParam.width > 0) {
        newImg = [newImg crop:CGRectMake(0, 0, cropParam.width, cropParam.height)];
    }

    // Create a button for the image
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentX + margin, 
                                                                  currentY + margin, 
                                                                  newImg.size.width, 
                                                                  newImg.size.height)];

    [button setImage:newImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:button];

    currentX += 2 * margin + newImg.size.width;

    if (currentX > viewWidth) {
        currentX = 0;
        currentY += 2 * margin + newImg.size.height; 
        currentH = newImg.size.height;
    }
}
self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(viewWidth, currentY);
```

}

The problem is that when the view appears, it is black. The button appear only when scrolling the view.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not triggering a redraw action - from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView):

> When the actual content of your view changes, it is your responsibility to notify the system that your view needs to be redrawn. You do this by calling your view’s setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect: method of the view. These methods let the system know that it should update the view during the next drawing cycle. Because it waits until the next drawing cycle to update the view, you can call these methods on multiple views to update them at the same time.

Comment: I've tried putting setneedsdisplay at the end of the drawrect or in the createView but doesn't change anything.